# $\int_0^a \mid f(t) \mid dt \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow f = 0 $?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I was reading a proof and I stucked at some point that I don't understand. Let's consider norm : $$||f||_1 = \int_0^1 |f(t)| dt$$

Now I will cite a part of the proof that I don't get

[image]

I don't understand this reasoning marked in yellow rectangle. The inequalities above says that:
$$0 \le \int_0^a|f(t)|dt \le something$$ where $something \rightarrow 0 $. So how can say by this argument that $\int_0^a|f(t)|dt = 0$ ?

If something is not understandble you can find full proof here: [https://www.math.kit.edu/iana3/~schnaubelt/media/fa14-skript.pdf](https://www.math.kit.edu/iana3/%7Eschnaubelt/media/fa14-skript.pdf) (on page 5)

Comment: Simplified, you have something like "$A$ is a real number such that, for every $n$, $$0 \leq A \leq x_n$$ where $x_n \to 0$."  Can you see why this forces $A=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $something = k(n)$ and suppose
$$  0 < \int_0^a |f(x)| \,\mathrm{d}x = \varepsilon \leq k(n) \text{.}  $$

Since $k(n) \rightarrow 0$, there exists an $N$ such that for $n > N$, $k(n) < \varepsilon/2$, violating the inequality.  Therefore, $\varepsilon \not > 0$ and the integral is zero.

In different words, the integral is squeezed between $0$ below and an infinite set of values of $k(n)$ above and the infimum of these upper bounds is also $0$, so the integral has nowhere to be other than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac12-\frac1n\geqslant a$, you have that $f_n(t)=0$ on $[0,a]$, and therefore$$\int_0^a|f(t)|\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^a|f(t)-f_n(t)|\,\mathrm dt.$$So, actually $\int_0^a|f(t)-f_n(t)|\,\mathrm dt$ does not depend upon the choice of $n$. But, on the other hand,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a|f(t)-f_n(t)|\,\mathrm dt=0.$$So, $\int_0^a|f(t)|\,\mathrm dt=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a squeeze theorem from a theory of limits. If you have three sequences $\{x_n\},\{y_n\},\{z_n\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n\leq y_n \leq z_n$ for all $n$ and if $x_n$ and $z_n$ converge to $A\in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ then $y_n$ also coverges to $A$.